# What is known about the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

I was wondering about the quadratic closure of the field of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ($p$ prime) exists. What is known about it? Is there any explicit description of such a quadratic closure? Does it occur naturally in number theory?

I was thinking about a construction in geometry, that I would like to "port" to the $p$-adic numbers, and I was led to the questions above.

Comment: http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~woodbury/research/quadexts.pdf might be interesting for you. Have not checked in detail though.

Comment: @ThorWittich, thank you, I had just stumbled on it, almost at the same time. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $p\ne 2$ $$K=\bigcup_n \Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{2^n},p^{1/2^n})=\bigcup_n \Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^{2^n}-1},p^{1/2^n})$$ contains the square root of all its elements.

Proof : the binomial series $(1+x)^{1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1/2\choose k} x^k$ converges for $v(x)>0$

Comment: Thank you! Can provide a little more details please? The $\zeta$s are primitive roots of unity, right? I will think about it tomorrow. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you know that $\bigcup_n \Bbb{F}_{p^{2^n}}=\bigcup_n \Bbb{F}_p(\zeta_{p^{2^n}-1})$ is the quadratic closure of $\Bbb{F}_p$, do you know that the roots of unity of the residue field lift to the p-adic field

Comment: $ \Bbb{F}_{p^f}^*$ is cyclic with $p^f-1$ elements ie. $ \Bbb{F}_{p^f}=\Bbb{F}_p(\zeta_{p^f-1})$

Comment: Thank you, so this explains why K is the union on the right-hand side. What about the union in the middle please?

Comment: Ok, so if $y$ is an element of $K$, then we kind of factor out from it the term with the most negative exponent of $p$? Is that basically your idea? I think I got it.

Comment: Every element of $K^*$ is of the form $p^{a/2^b} \zeta_{p^{2^c}-1}^d (1+x)$ with $v(x)> 0$